# Avoid reprocessing of messages in Kafka Consumer

Tags: apache-kafka

If while processing a batch of records inside a pool loop the consumer crashes before manually synchrounous commit the offset, a reprocessing of these messages will occur by the consumer that gets the ownership of the partition these messages came from. The only way to avoid this is using exactly once processing by using transactions and an idempotent producer?

How do we manage rebalance?
If by any chance a rebalance happens while processing a batch of records inside a pool loop and do synchronous commit at end of loop, when the poll method is executed again i believe there is no need to commit the messages inside a rebalance listener, once the messages are already commited. Have we to commit again inside the rebalancer listener??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> only way to avoid this is using exactly once processing by using transactions and an idempotent producer

Basically, yes. Transactions are enabled by default in latest Kafka producer client. *However*, consuming this data only applies to the Kafka transactions themselves, and does not prevent reprocessing "equivalent records". For this, you'd need to compare the deserialized data against some externally stored hash / lookup table, for example.

More detail - https://developer.confluent.io/learn/kafka-transactions-and-guarantees/

> How do we manage rebalance

Use a [ConsumerRebalanceListener](https://kafka.apache.org/35/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerRebalanceListener.html). The Javadoc gives an exact example how you'd commit and seek the offsets to a committed value.

> Have we to commit again inside the rebalancer listener?

There is no guarantee the "end of the poll loop" will be reached, so yes.

Comment: And that assignment changes during a rebalance. Was that not what you were asking about? During a poll, you should catch WakeupException. There's no guarantee the end of the poll loop/function where you'd otherwise commit will be reached, since any exception could be thrown

Comment: Thanks for your anwser. I read the javadoc it says 
> "This callback will only execute in the user thread as part of the poll(long) call whenever partition assignment changes."

So to be executed we are back inside pool method call again and hence we already commited the offset at the end of the poll loop. So i got this doubt, do i need to commit inside the rebalance listener?

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting "part of" since the listener runs on a different thread, and doesn't return control back to the poll loop after the partitions had been revoked.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. So if rebalance it's triggered when the consumer thread is inside the poll loop, and we commit the offsets iinside the rebalance listener in another thread, when the consumer thread reach end it will execute commit again  correct?

Comment: Committing more than once isn't an issue, if that's what you're worried about. You can also add logic to not commit higher/lower values than what was already committed